# Problems with fxFlex API for Angular

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I'm trying to add a nice contact form for my website and i'm using fxFlex to organize it.
I would have this template for my contact page but i'm not using well fxFlex and have a lot of problems with that: [Template example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB28H.jpg)

Currently, i have this in my code (i didn't add the content to show you only the divs) :

```
<div id="background">
  <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayout.xs="column">

    <div>
      <!-- Contact form will be here -->
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <!-- Google map will be here -->
      </div>

      <div>
        <!-- Coordonates will be here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i also have a background image in a div but I think it is not a problem.

I hope you will be able to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.contact {
  width: 550px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.right-side {
  width: 200px;
}

.map {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.coord {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayout.xs="column">

    <div fxFlex="550px" class="contact">
      <!-- Contact form will be here -->
    </div>

    <div fxFlex="250px" class="right-side">
      <div class="map">
        <!-- Google map will be here -->
      </div>

      <div class="coord">
        <!-- Coordonates will be here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude !
The only problem I see is that if i'm in my phone the 3 boxes are not in columns, what should I change ?

Comment: Hope this helps you - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed?file=app%2Ftest.component.ts